# Aggregate data.table by one column and keep another id column in the result

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table in R to be grouped by values of one column and find the outliers in each group.  BUT I need to keep the id column (not included in the aggregation). For example, for the data table a as below, I want to find outliers of Hours by class and output it with corresponding id.

```
      Hours       id class
 1: 100.000 30298340     M
 2:   4.776 30310183     M
 3:   1.560 30312576     M
 4:  11.520 30336159     M
 5:   3.288 30331383     M
 6:   6.552 30364533     M
 7:   5.064 30365224     M
 8:  27.768 30365394     C
 9:   4.992 30365211     M
 10:  25.536 30365603     M
 11:   8.568 30337051     M
 12:   5.112 30337052     C
 13:   2.352 30284703     M
 14:  23.784 30325405     M
 15:  16.464 30327152     M
 16:  24.336 30351237     M
 17:   3.192 30352117     M
 18:  24.312 30324926     M
 19:  23.160 30325670     M
 20:   4.176 30324906     M
```

Then I used the following code to find outliers.

```
 temp<-a[,.(Hours=boxplot.stats(Hours,coef=3,do.conf=F)$out,M=boxplot.stats(Hours,do.conf=F
  )$stats[3]),by=class]
```

temp[Hours>M] will give me the outlier above median and median as a reference.

```
     class Hours    M
  1:     M   100 7.56
```

But how can I change the aggregation line to include id for the outlier row?

Since my original table is very large, I don't want to merge the temp with original data. Also, because this is only a small piece of large existing program, I am trying to keep the main structure of temp result with id column added so temp can be passed into the next block of computation. Ideally, is there an simple way to tweak the data.table aggregation line to fulfill my request? Thank you!!!

---

Here is an additional question in the same scenarios. Now if I have 3 more columns in the original data, i.e. age, gender, etc. How can I keep them all in the outlier output? I can simply repeat Eric's code with id replaced with other variable and add in the data.table step:

```
age=age[which(Hours %in% boxplot.stats(Hours, coef = 3, do.conf = FALSE)$out)],
gender=gender[which(Hours %in% boxplot.stats(Hours, coef = 3, do.conf = FALSE)$out)],
```

But it would be a tedious work if there are more columns to add. I am thinking of doing the following:

```
  keyname<-c("age", "gender","id")
  temp <- a[, .(Hours = boxplot.stats(Hours, coef = 3, do.conf = FALSE)$out,
          M = boxplot.stats(Hours, do.conf = FALSE)$stats[3],
          lapply(c(1:length(keyname)),function(x) keyname[x]=get(keyname[x])[which(Hours) %in% boxplot.stats(Hours, coef = 3, do.conf = FALSE)$out)]),
      by = class]
```

However, it doesn't work. Any further suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: As the 'id' are unique, use `:=` to create the 'Hours' column

Comment: If you only want to subset the data by keeping Hours > median(Hours), then you can use this: subset(df, df$Hours>median(df$Hours)).

Comment: @user108363 They want the median (or whatever that is) computed per `class`, I guess, since they wrote `by=class`.

Comment: @Frank thanks, I missed that. Then, you could try something like: library(dplyr)
new_df <- df %>%group_by(class) %>% summarize(median_hours_by_class = median(Hours), Hours=Hours, class=class, id=id)
subset(new_df, new_df$Hours>new_df$median_hours_by_class)

Comment: Hello user1083637, I need the outliers above medians by class not just data points above median. But you provide me a good example/possible way by using dplyr. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `which` and subsetting to make the column.

```
temp <- a[, .(Hours = boxplot.stats(Hours, coef = 3, do.conf = FALSE)$out,
              M = boxplot.stats(Hours, do.conf = FALSE)$stats[3],
              id = id[which(Hours %in% boxplot.stats(Hours, coef = 3, do.conf = FALSE)$out)]),
          by = class]

> temp
   class Hours     M       id
1:     M   100  7.56 30298340
2:     C    NA 16.44       NA

> temp[Hours > M]
   class Hours    M       id
1:     M   100 7.56 30298340
```

Comment: Thank you Eric Watt. This is exactly what I want, simple but efficient. It does add wanted id column within data.table aggregation step. Appreciate it!

Comment: Could you please help me a little more? @EricWatt  I added an additional question in my original post. I have 7 more columns to keep. I think your solution should still work, but it requires a super long repeated code inside the data.table step. Is there a simpler way (at least one that make code look cleaner)? Thank you!

Comment: If the columns are unique for each id, which columns like `age` and `gender` seem like they should be, you could use `merge`. After making the `temp` table above, try `merge(temp, a[, .(id, age, gender)], by = "id", all.x=TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @EricWatt. The original data is very large so I hesitate to merge. Does merging take longer time when one of the tables is very large? If yes, I guess I will just repeat the code with different variables in the aggregation.

Comment: Depends on what 'very large' is, but my initial answer would be no, it shouldn't take long. Won't know until you try though. Merging `data.table`s can be quite fast and memory efficient. I just tried a million rows of random data and it took less than 100 milliseconds.